# Allure reports. Load english version by default

Tags: testing, allure

Is there any flag to force Allure reports to be displayed in English by default?

I'm sending them to Amazone server but the dashboard (reports/reports15/allure-maven-plugin/#/) is displayed in Russian. What does this depend on?

Answer (score 2):

Old Allure versions (prior to 1.5.*) use browser language as default report language. Newest versions should use English by default